# Who broke into Outpost 31's blood plasma storage?

Tags: the-thing-1982

We're told that Garry's key to the blood safe is the only one, and he gave it to Copper immediately after Copper suggested the blood serum test, and when the cast discovers all the blood plasma has been ruined Copper claims to still have it.

But Garry and Copper both passed MacReady's blood test later in the movie, so neither of them were Things during the events described above. It seems like that rules out everyone as a possible suspect, so I'm not even sure who *could* have ruined the blood, much less who did.

Is there any evidence as to how one of the Things managed to get into the safe, destroy the blood and lock it back up afterward?

Comment: I've asked producer Stuart Cohen and director John Carpenter about this.  I'll update my answer if and when they reply.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### *Update:  I've asked producer Stuart Cohen and director John Carpenter about this.  I'll amend my answer if and when they reply.*

### TL;DR:  [We don't know.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/faq#.2.1.12)

### Background:

Despite the fact that Copper had the keys at one point, there is a much more important incident prior to that. When Split-Face is moved to the storage room, Garry gives Windows the keys to the storage room so he and Bennings can move the gear out of the room.  They proceed to do so, and while Windows is away for a moment, Split-Face assimilates Bennings.

If you watch the scene in which Windows discovers Bennings in the middle of being assimilated by the Thing, and turn the volume up, you'll hear Windows drop the keys to the blood storage cooler.  He doesn't pick them up again.

When the survivors find the blood cooler open, and the bags of blood destroyed, they accuse one another of being the culprit, but there is simply no way to determine who was really responsible.

### Whodunnit:

I think it's safe to assume that the guilty party was a Thing.  As such, here are our candidates:

#### Known Things:

- Bennings-Thing:  Although it was still in the process of assuming the form of Bennings, it was clearly the best placed to find the keys.  However, I don't think it had either the motivation or the time to get the keys, go to the blood cooler, destroy the blood, and then flee the building.  Because the men only realize that the Thing replicates its victims after they find Bennings-Thing, the blood test idea had yet to be raised when Bennings-Thing was killed.  Thus, aside from the problem of the lack of time, Bennings-Thing also had no *reason* to destroy the blood supply.
- Norris-Thing:  We don't know when Norris was assimilated, but this is plausible.  He knew that a blood test was in the works, so he had every reason to tamper with the blood supply.
- Palmer-Thing:  He was assimilated very early on, knew about the blood test, and had the time and motivation to destroy the blood supply.
- Blair-Thing:  Again, we don't know when he was assimilated, but he was a biologist, so he knew the potential use for the blood.  However, he was locked up in the tool shed by the time the blood was destroyed, so he probably didn't do it.

#### Non-Things:

We can rule out most or all of the following:

- Windows:  Not a Thing (he is later attacked by Palmer-Thing).
- Nauls:  Not a Thing (he is later attacked by Blair-Thing).
- MacReady:  [Not a Thing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/93891/44025).
- Copper:  Not a Thing (he is later attacked by Norris-Thing);  came up with the idea of a blood test;  discovered that the blood had been destroyed.
- Childs:  [Almost certainly not a Thing.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/93891/44025)
- Clark:  Not a Thing (he is later killed by MacReady).
- Garry:  Not a Thing (he is later attacked by Blair-Thing).

#### Status Unknown:

In the category of "could have been a Thing, but probably wasn't", we have only one person:

- Fuchs:  [A deleted scene shows Palmer and Childs discovering the body of Fuchs impaled on a door in the greenhouse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95015/44025).  Since impalement wouldn't kill a Thing, this would clear him of responsibility.  However, in the finished movie, his fate is left unclear, so it is just barely possible to imagine him being involved.  Still, it is far fetched and largely implausible.

### The Best Explanation:

John Carpenter has never commented on this issue, as far as I know, and if he was asked to do so, he would almost certainly say "I don't know", as he does in response to pretty much every question about the movie.  Therefore, as in most cases, the best source of information about this subject is the fansite Outpost 31<sup>1</sup>.

The following comes from that site's [FAQ](http://www.outpost31.com/movie/faq.html) section:

> Q. Who got to the blood and how?
>
> A: This is a question that has no definite answers, but there is a trail of actual events and logic that brings about some strong speculations.
>
> The keys, which play a crucial role to the sabotaged blood scene, disappear from the action when Windows discovers the Bennings-Thing in mid-assimilation.  He had gone to get the keys from Garry, came back, dropped them and ran out of the room.  We don't see the keys show up again until right before the scene with the sabotaged blood.  Someone obviously found them, used them, and somehow got them inconspicuously back into the action.  (A good guess would be by placing them in or near Garry's quarters.)  Watch Windows' face as they argue about who had access to the blood.  His guilt from dropping the keys and not speaking up about it is a nice touch.
>
> As for who did the deed, when Copper discovers the sabotaged blood it is still pouring out of the fridge, suggesting a very recent incident.  (Contrast this to the script and novel where the blood is already fully dried.)  Both Palmer and Norris are not present after locking up Blair when the men come up with the idea for a blood serum test.  Perfect time to hit the blood supply. The other remaining men, Windows, Nauls, and Clark were most likely at their respective areas.  (Clark distracted with his dead dogs and Windows probably recovering from his recent beating.)  These two, Palmer and Norris, most likely Things now working together, were up to no good.

---

<sup>1</sup> How reliable is the information on the Outpost 31 site?  So reliable that, when the prequel was being made, and it was discovered that the studio hadn't preserved any blueprints for the Norwegian base set, the director of the prequel turned to Outpost 31, and was quickly provided with an exact blueprint of the set by the fans, based on careful examination of the relevant scenes from the 1982 film.

Answer (score 0):

Spoke with my better half about this: Perhaps the thing can use prior knowledge from previous hosts (such as the Norwegians) To understand that it needs to eliminate the plasma because, perhaps, there were prior attempts of blood testing in the Norwegian station. So the thing only needed to assimilate somebody with a basic familiarity of the station, then use the knowledge it learned from the Norway station to destroy anything that can help the current station do research on how the Thing spreads.

Does this sound preposterous? Remember, the Blair thing was building a flying saucer. Blair doesn't know how to build a saucer, but the aliens that crashed in the antarctic certainly did. Those aliens who were probably infected by the thing, lent their knowledge of space travel to the Thing. So why can't the thing steal scientific knowledge from one human host and transfer it to another? If that's the case, then the Thing could possibly be one of the most intelligent aliens out there, not just a killing machine...

Comment: Interesting idea. But how would this explain how the Thing was able to ruin the plasma, even though neither person with the key to the blood safe could have been a Thing? The other answer seems to address this.

Comment: If you go by the novella, the Thing *is* one of the most intelligent beings out there. Far, far smarter than humans. The novella also implies that the assimilation/mimicry ability was not necessarily innate to the race, but came about because it had discovered the deepest secrets of Biology and turned it to its use.

Answer (score 0):

We're dealing with a shape shifting creature with the minds of very skilled and capable men by the time the blood is destroyed.

There are more then just one way to enter a safe, destroy the contents, and leave without a key. Another possibility is that the key to the safe was useless in the first place as the thing is a sum of its whole. And that whole can, as stated above and in the film's and story can change its shape.

Most safes are not sealed. There is actually a wide gap area between the door and the frame. A very motivated thing, any one of them at the time could have waited for the room to be empty, walk up to the safe and reach inside, reconfigure and get it all in a matter of moments or minutes and no one would be the wiser.

Even if the safe where sealed, that seal would only be ment to keep the environment inside and outside segregated from the other while closed. It keeps the cold in and the heat out. Again, a motivated thing creature would find very little pause to get past that seal when reaching into the Safe with out a key.

The keys being lost would make no difference. It's a red herring that is used as a plot device to further the men's distrust of each other to further muddle the identity of the real culprit.

If a key is all you need to get the safe open, a basic locksmithing knowledge will allow anyone to open the safe with a basic tool. If the safe had a combo, the things hearing and nerve sensitivity could be enhanced so that they could just crack the combo of the safe. If both key and combo is required, it will take just a bit longer but it can be done.

I personally don't even think that the safe was opened at all and it was destroyed while it was still shut. I also believe that the real culprit is likely one of the finger pointer when they all discovered the problem.

By this point there is clearly two or more things in the group. According to the story, and vaguely suggested in the film's. The think has a telepathic communication with each other. If that is true, then they like in the story can telepathically read our unguarded human minds with incredible ease and would be able to suss out the plans of the men with a little digging around a few key minds.

This makes me think that at least a couple of these men might have had a sort of natural latent telepathic resistance or ability that they themselves don't know about. Mac being one of those sort giving him the ability to actually surprise the thing.

The point is that they is more then one way to skin a cat, just because the key is accounted for or not at the time of destruction of the blood, that doesn't mean that t was needed in the first place. It's clear that the humans would not have done it and at the time it happened, the outpost take over was well in progress by the time it happened, and they would.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much who would have the skills, opportunity, to open the fridge/safe containing the blood samples, whether with keys or by picking the lock, but who could have known, prior to Dr Copper revealing his idea about the blood serum test, which we are shown in the movie.

For when he unveils his thoughts on the blood serum test, only five of the characters are present, that we can see anyhow, and they are, Garry on the left, next is Dr Copper, then Childs, next is Fuchs, then last of all is McCready, so how could anyone else have known prior to this scene, about the blood serum test, other than Dr Copper?

As Dr Copper isn't likely to have spoken to Palmer, or anyone else, about his idea, other than perhaps, Blair, Norris, or Fuchs, as they are the only other scientific minded people.

Blair was locked away, Fuchs was present when Copper revealed his thoughts on the serum test, yet was never taken over by the Thing, so that leaves Norris, who in my opinion is the shadow who gets assimilated early on.

Palmer isn't likely to have been informed of any medical/scientific ideas, unless he read it somewhere in Coppers notes, from the instance of Windows dropping the keys to them turning up when the sabotage has taken place, is really sketchy.

Yet, Palmer as a mechanic is most probably more likely to have the skills to pick the lock, so I guess the answer will forever be a mystery, I've been watching this film for 37 years, yet I'm still none the wiser!

Although thinking about it, if both Palmer and Norris were both Things by this time, then it could have been a joint effort, maybe both of them committed the sabotage of the blood samples?

Also, if whoever sabotaged the blood store did use the keys, yet they never stole them from Garry, whilst he was sleeping, or otherwise occupied {showering}, then they would have to have discovered the keys in the storage room, where Windows dropped them.

Otherwise why didn't Garry or McCready find them on the floor in the scene in the storage room, just after Bennings was incinerated, where Garry is struggling to understand what just took place.

So there's a really short space of time, within which the culprit had to commit sabotage of the blood packs, between Windows dropping the keys, then when McCready and Garry are seen in the storage room, I'd say around 15-20 minutes tops, and Bennings wasn't the best placed to take the keys, because he had already fled through the broken window, so was already outside when Windows dropped them.

Wouldn't Garry remember who returned the keys to him after he passed them to Windows, this is the real question, when did Garry notice that the keys had been returned to him, how did he notice, did someone hand them back to him, or were they mysteriously back on his belt attachment, or perhaps curiously on his bedside table sometime later on?

Yet, are the storage room keys which Windows drops, the same set of keys as those that open the blood store, we suppose so, but we aren't given the relevant information to deduce exactly what happened, there are too many open ended story lines, to figure out what occurred, it's as if they're teasing us, why include Windows dropping the keys without showing it, we only hear them drop, if it isn't relevant

If this is how events took place, then it was just a stroke of luck for whoever found the keys in the storage room, between Windows dropping them, then re-entering the room with McCready and Fuchs, and then Garry and McCready entering the storage room after Bennings was burnt to death, as surely one of them would've found the keys on the floor in one of those scenes, as Windows only dropped them there, a short while earlier.

Yet, that window of opportunity is unlikely the time in which the sabotage took place, as it isn't until the following day when Dr Copper reveals his thoughts on the blood serum test, and the time between when Dr Copper tells the four other characters to when the sabotaged blood is found seems to be too short in which to carry out the destruction of the blood packs, this seems to point to the sabotage taking place through the night.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Would you mind splitting this up into a few paragraphs to make it a bit more reader-friendly, though?

Comment: Sure thing.I sometimes forget about paragraphing, I suppose it's the continuity of my thought process, I'll make sure to only post clear cut paragraphs in future. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same evidence everyone else has- This is my 'own personal opinion', just like everyone else has theirs. :D

But my circumstantial evidence is that it was Blair, who had motive, rapid onset insanity, and the scientific forethought to destroy as much biological 'Thing-food' as he could before being caught. This is all before he was infected.  I give him a break, he was only trying to save the World.

Two known Things, Palmer and Norris, are seen and pretty much accounted for from when Bennings gets fried, to when Blair fires his first shot. Neither had time to screw with the blood, before or after the idea of the Test. Plus, Garry had his keys back by then.

Palmer or Norris are not present when Doc mentions the test for the first time. The very next scene is the blood. Neither would even had time to hear about the test, much less sabotage it.

Blair had plenty of time to do the blood, kill the dogs, wreck the vehicles, and no one noticed.  They were all occupied with the Bennings and other bodies burn-a-thon.
(Clark is also not seen during these events, but I doubt that he wrecked the blood lol)

To me this is much more likely a scenario than a Thing picking the lock, or using tentacles to get inside, etc.

Haha  no one thought to go out and ask Blair if he did it.

Please poke holes in this theory!
Another mystery...  what happened to the gun that Blair was using?

Comment: If you have a question you should ask it instead of adding it to the end of your answer.

Comment: You have a point about the lack of opportunity for either Palmer or Norris to have destroyed the blood packs after having heard about the proposed blood serum test. That said, I don't buy into your motive for an uninfected Blair doing it. I mean, "Thing food"...? Seriously? An infected person had a much stronger motive to destroy those blood packs than an uninfected person did. If it anything, it would've made more sense for an uninfected Blair to stash the blood packs away somewhere so he could conduct a blood serum test himself, rather than taking that option entirely off the table.

Comment: It makes zero sense for Blair to stash blood packs away. He wasn't interested in a test, he was eliminating bio-mass, same reason he killed the dogs. Plus whole blood has to be refrigerated or it is unusable very quickly.  Other Things had more motiveation, but neither the time or the keys.

Comment: I don't think Blair killed the dogs to eliminate bio-mass. He did it to prevent the spread of the infection. Destroying the blood packs didn't obviously do anything to further that goal. I agree that he didn't seem interested in running tests. He seemed intent on ensuring that no one got out of there alive, infected or otherwise. That doesn't mean that hiding the blood packs wasn't a logical thing to do. It's just that that's not where his head was at. As far as keeping the blood packs refrigerated goes, that shouldn't have been too hard, considering that they were in Antarctica.

Comment: lol  yep  At any rate, he wasn't exactly thinking 100% clearly.  Plus, Smirnoff.

Answer (score -1):

Blair sabotaged the blood.
Around the same time he killed the dogs.

• Blair drinks half a bottle of Smirnoff, grabs a gun, and starts his decent into bonkers.
• Bennings gets lassoo-ed and infected, and gets busted by Windows, who then drops the keys.
• While Bennings runs off and is chased by everyone, broiled, etc.,  Blair discovers keys on the floor. Blair and Clark are not shown during Bennings Jubilee outside.
• Blair does a saba-tajj on the blood fridge, then either drops the keys back where he found them, or leaves them on the pool table or something for Garry to casually pick them up later, because Garry is kind of a dope.
• Blair then goes on to secretly kill the dogs and ruin the vehicles while everyone is distracted burning all the bodies. He runs in as Mac spots him and yells, which means Blair is short on time now that he's been made. Wrecks remaining equipment and radio, etc. then throws gun. Job complete.

Checking the blood bank is the last thing people would notice that he wrecked, with all the other stuff going on.
Nobody checks the blood until they think of the test...

Why would Blair destroy the blood? He’s not infected at this point.

Same reason he killed the dogs and destroyed everything else, he didn’t want anything escaping or aiding worldwide infection. Plus, crazy.

The keys were unaccounted for from the time Windows dropped them to where Doc got them from Garry and discovered the blood. Palmer and Norris are seen in all of the Benning’s death scenes and body burning scenes, And we know Blair was up to no good during those events.

It would have been the perfect time…

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back this up, or is it purely your own personal opinion that this is what happened?